# Has anyone solved the issue of alphanet crashing once it syncs and consistently showing 0 peers?

Tags: node, alphanet

This is just for tezos-node on alphanet, I've recently noticed that the number of peers doesn't go past 5 resulting in the node taking forever to sync and goes down to 0 once the node is synced, resulting in validator failure, even when increasing the number of peers in the config file, the validator crashes and fails once the node catches up.

The specific error shows:

```
node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline:                                 I/O error

node.validator.bootstrap_pipeline: Unexpected error (validator): Error:
```

Comment: I already looked at that answer and it lacks a lot of elements that are in my question, my errors are specific, and on top of that, I've implemented all those solutions, adding peers doesn't work, amount of peers are still 0 and the error is very specific, unless you can show me where that specific error shows up in that post.